# Google Maps. Определить ближайшие населённые пункты?

Tags: google-maps-api

Можно ли средствами API гуглмапс определить ближайшие населённые пункты относительно заданной точки? Не одного ближайшего города, а нескольких. Геокодер определяет только один ближайший город, а надо как миниум 3. Пока что единственное решение, это где то взять базу населённых пунков с коррдинатами и расчётным способом определять ближайшие города.

Answer (score 1):

Надо взять некоторый радиус и задать несколько запросов для точек по кругу с заданным радиусом. Радиус можно увеличить если на все точки определяется один город.